# Load Razor Component in Layout Page

Tags: razor, blazor

I have a Blazor WebAssembly Hosted Application.  My intention is to use Server for some of the site and WebAssembly pages for the remainder so they can run off-line.

I have what should be a simple question about the Server side.

I have the following:
Pages/_Layout.cshtml
Pages/Index.cshtml
Pages/Components\MyComponent.razor

/Pages/_Layout.cshtml

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="/lib/twitter-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <base href="~/" />  
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        The Layout Header
        WHAT MAGIC GOES HERE TO INSERT MyComponent.razor
    </div>
    <div class="m-2">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

/Pages/Index.cshtml

```
@page
@model MyApp.Server.Pages.IndexModel
@{
}

<h1>Index Page</h1>
```

/Pages/Components/MyComponent.razor

```
<h3>My Component</h3>
```

My output is:

The Layout Header

The Index Page

I want:

The Layout Header

My Component

The Index Page

How do I add that razor component to my _Layout.cshtml page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your _`Layout.cshtml page` is a `Razor Pages` page, right? So you can use the component Html tag to render a Blzor component in your Razor Pages page, something like this:

```
<div>
        The Layout Header
        WHAT MAGIC GOES HERE TO INSERT MyComponent.razor
        <component type="typeof(MyComponent)" render- 
             mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</div>
```

Note that the above requires you to set some configuration for this to work.

Comment: Oh, geez!!  Was using mode="Server", not mode="ServerPrerendered".  Thank you!!!